# How do I color top border of rounded cell?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uibezierpath, cashapelayer

I have to make a collectionView which cells are rounded from left and right, It's ok with code below

```
    let maskPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds,
                                byRoundingCorners: corners,
                                cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 10.0, height: 10.0))
    let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    maskLayer.frame = self.bounds
    maskLayer.path  = maskPath.CGPath
    self.layer.mask = maskLayer
    self.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

but one more thing, I want to give border color to top of each cell,

[image]

Any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: Border color? You can use UIBezierPath to draw a line that correspond to it?

Comment: I tried to draw a line its ok, problem is rounded part.

Comment: The Corner Radius is just a "quart circle". UIBezierPath has method to draw circle part. It's not complicated. You go from 0,10, draw a circle from center 10,10 with 10 as radius, then draw a line from 10,0 to width-10,0, draw a circle from center width-10,10 with 10 as radius.

Answer (score 0):

Some differences, so:

```
let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 100))

let shapeOfView = CAShapeLayer()
shapeOfView.position = view.center
shapeOfView.bounds = view.frame
shapeOfView.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: view.bounds, byRoundingCorners: [.topLeft, .topRight], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 10.0, height: 10)).cgPath        

view.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
view.layer.mask = shapeOfView
```

Comment: I wrote Swift 3 code, so you may need to correct some statements.

Comment: line is ok but It should include rounded part.

Comment: Oh, it isn't. I am going to investigate how I could help.

Comment: Code only round a view from topLeft and topRight, put it to playground project you will see, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do,

```
  var border = CALayer()
    border.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame), 1) //set width and heigt (thickness of your border)
    border.backgroundColor = color.CGColor; //desired color
    yourCell.layer.addSublayer(border)
```

Comment: I have problem with rounded part, line is ok.

Answer (score -1):

add CAlayer as a sublayer of cell

```
    CALayer *borderLayer = [CALayer layer];

    borderLayer.borderColor = [UIColor greenColor].CGColor;

    borderLayer.borderWidth = 3.0f;

    borderLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.frame.size.width, 1);

    [cell.layer addSublayer:borderLayer];
```